# Integration of facebook opengraph to wordpress?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, sorting, facebook-opengraph, posts

First let me explain my predicament,

I am currently developing a wordpress site which implements facebook apps for my post likes/comments. and one function of the site is that there is a tab/page where in the posts are sorted based on number of comments and facebook likes.

I have used multiple resources to try to achieve this but in the end i still havent gotten the feature i wanted. i used this http://www.flexostudio.com/flexo-facebook-manager.html and this http://www.metronet.no/sorting-posts-by-facebook-likes-in-wordpress/ as my reference.

Here is the problem i am facing, I already implemented the tutorials i saw, but then it still doesnt work, so it made me wonder. so i tried to trace the root of the problem, im not sure if this is the cause but one problem i saw is when i used FB's debug tool, i get these warnings

```
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. Inferred Property:    The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Im not sure if the problem im facing is due to mis configuration of facebook app or something, has someone experienced the same problem? Or does anyone have any other resources to be able to help me achieve the post sorting based on FB likes and comments?

Any type of help would be gladly appreciated,

Regards,
RJ

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an already built plugin for this, e.g. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-connect/

if you insist on your own, see how it is done - http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-connect/tags/2.0.3/src/WordpressConnect.php

Comment: Hi Mr scibuff, first of all, thank you for the quick response.I have browsed through the resource you gave which is the wordpress connect, but it doesnt seem to have the feature i am looking for which is to be able to sort WP posts based on number of likes and comments.